# Angular.js with Handlebars

Tags: angularjs, express, data-binding, handlebars.js, mean

I am new to MEAN stack and had already developed codes using handlebars templating engine in express. But now I want to use feature of angular two way data binding. Syntax used by Handlebars and Angular js is same . How to avoid the clash of syntax between angular and handlebars??

Comment: The solution at your question is on this post : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366412/using-express-handlebars-and-angular-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366412/using-express-handlebars-and-angular-js)

Comment: Yeah I have seen that . But where do I need to register handlebars helper??

Comment: I think you can put your register in a script loaded before the angularJs script.