# add meteor packages in angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm relatively new to meteor, but have already some experience in AngularJS. Therefore I have "angular-meteor" installed. 
I also have a bit played around with it and am very happy with it. Now I have only the problem that if I, for example, wants the package "meteor-uploads" use, I always receive the error message:

```
Token '>' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [> upload_bootstrap] starting at [> upload_bootstrap].
```

if I want to use the package, by `{{> upload_bootstrap}}`.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

I can access the package with:

```
import upload_bootstrap from 'meteor/tomi:upload_bootstrap';
```

How can I now render it to my view?

Comment: Are you using Angular or Blaze?  That looks like the Blaze Spacebars notation to me.  Forgive me if I am incorrect, I don't know much about Angular.  If you are trying to co-mingle them, I think there is a way to do that by changing the interpolate start and end symbols.

Comment: @CodeChimp is right - the client package for [meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) has a dependency on Blaze. It can't be used with Angular (unless you hack it to pieces ...)

Comment: Maybe try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366412/using-express-handlebars-and-angular-js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client package for [meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads) was designed to be used with Blaze only (it has a dependency on Blaze). You won't be able to use it with Angular unless you're willing to port a lot of the code over yourself.

If you're looking for a popular Meteor based file upload solution (that isn't tied to a specific view layer which means it can be used with Angular), take a look at [edgee:slingshot](https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot).