# Use ng-bind to display image

Tags: angularjs

Im use handlebars so I cant use {{expression}}. So I change everything to ng-bind. Everything work find but I cant find a way to make it work with img.

```
ng-src="{{x.img}}" 
ng-src="?"
```

Answer (score 0):

please see it [Using Express Handlebars and Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366412/using-express-handlebars-and-angular-js) .  Handlebars content may be escaped in one of two ways, inline escapes or raw block helpers. Inline escapes created by prefixing a mustache block with \ . So you can try this :

`ng-src="\{{x.img}}"`